# Check if click event was already triggered using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my input element:

```
 <input  #fileInputID type="file" (change)="startUpload($event.target.files)">
```

It placed into a div that uses this is my viewchild:

```
 @ViewChild('fileInputID',{ static: false }) fileInput :ElementRef;
```

I need to trigger the click event through the input or the div that contains it.
When I click the outer div I call for a method the run this line:

```
this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
```

But the problem is that when I click on the internal input, I getting clicks events duplicates because I trigger a click event both on the outer div and input at the same time.

***So how can I detect if a click event already been triggered in order to prevent duplications?***

Comment: startUpload($event.target.files); $event.stopPropagation(); can work?

Comment: I tried it, but typescript not recognized event.stopPropagation

Comment: try to reproduce it in a stackblitz please

Comment: Try `(change)="startUpload($event)">`, now you have a handle on the event, so you should be able to do `stopPropagation` and then you can extract `target.files` to do the further processing.